# unable to solve converting csv to json due to comma in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

/* This code works fine, but i'm facing a problem when there is a comma involved in a particular column. That comma splits into a different column which I want to avoid.*/

/* is there a way while using "var split = line.Split(',');" it ignores the comma found in between texts*/

/* For Example : TST2.0_Performance_Re-order Tasks - Right Click Context Menu, move left/move right */

//After Context menu the comma gets separated into different column

```
   [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetProductDetail (string ProductName)
    {

        string csvurl = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["csvfileurl"];

        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(csvurl).Skip(1);

        List<Product> prdt = new List<Product>();
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            Product c1 = new Product();


            var split = line.Split(',');
            c1.ID = Int32.Parse(split[0]);
            c1.Area_Path = split[1];
            c1.IterationPath = split[2];
            c1.State = split[3];
            c1.Reason = split[4];
            c1.Priority = Int32.Parse(split[5]);
            c1.Severity = split[6];
            c1.Tags = split[7];
            c1.Title = split[8];
            c1.CreatedDate = split[9];
            c1.CreatedBy = split[10];
            c1.ResolvedDate = split[11];
            c1.ResolvedBy = split[12];
            c1.ClosedDate = split[13];
            c1.AssignedTo = split[14];
            prdt.Add(c1);




        }
```

Comment: If you can identify the cases, you can pre-clean the data. i.e. replace all instances of `Menu, ` with `Menu `

Comment: the problem is that the csv file is autogenerated and we cannot change any values. The entire process is automated. works perfectly fine if i manually delete the comma

Comment: You could put an "inline clean" into your code, You could use a command line tool to search and replace. There are many ways to clean the file. Your real problem is that there is no way to _automatically_ recognise whether a comma is valid or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? Hope this helps.

```
var split = Regex.Split(line, ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
```

Don't forget to use Regular expression namespace

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Comment: Thanks. Solved it

Comment: Great ! Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a CSV parser that deals with all of the edge-cases like these is not trivial.

You should consider using an existing parsing library like [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper).

I'm assuming that the case containing a comma has quotes? If there are no quotes, you are in trouble.
e.g.

```
  "1","John's toes","My first, bread"
```

You may be able to get away with splitting with `.Split(new[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None)`